# How to disable input in this supertrend pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=5
indicator("Supertrend", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

atrPeriod = input(9, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(4, "Factor", step = 0.01)

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)

bodyMiddle = plot((open + close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend = plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend = plot(direction < 0? na : supertrend, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

fill(bodyMiddle, upTrend, color.new(color.green, 90), fillgaps=false)
fill(bodyMiddle, downTrend, color.new(color.red, 90), fillgaps=false)
```

Comment: i don't want to enable ATR & Factor input from indicator setting.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the input with the value of your choice :

```
atrPeriod = 5 // input(9, "ATR Length")
factor = 4.0 // input.float(4, "Factor", step = 0.01)
```